# Is it possible to check for a shared border between various shapes in an inline SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an inline SVG of a map where each region is drawn as a separate shape. What I'd like to do is get a list of any neighbours that share a border with that shape.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I currently have:

https://jsfiddle.net/kzscxj30/

```
$( ".map" ).click(function( event ) {
    var $mapTarget = $( event.target );
        if ($mapTarget.is( "path" )) {
            $( ".region" ).attr("class", "region");
        $mapTarget.attr("class", "region active");
    } else {
        return;
    }
})
```

The idea is once a shape is clicked, it adds an 'active' class the shape and a 'neighbor' class to any touching shapes. For example, Region1 is neighbours with Region2 and Region3, so clicking Region1 should add the class 'neighbor' to both Region2 and Region3. Region2 and Region3 are not neighbours with each other, so clicking either would only add the neighbour class to Region1. Region4 is not a neighbour to any other shape, so it would not apply the neighbour class to anything.

I've considered comparing the coordinates of each shape to find a match, but I realised it's possible to have two shapes with a shared border but no shared coordinates.

It's possible this is more of an issue of not knowing how to articulate what I'm looking for!

Comment: What is your original issue you are trying to solve here? I feel you just encountered the common issue with svg maps of highlighting a region by using the stroke of the active one, and then realize that the stroke of neighbors are on top of this region. If so, **this** has a simple solution. "Finding all neighbors", is not precise enough. It might be possible to find all shapes that do overlap, but otherwise, if there is no overlap, the definition of "neighbor" must be defined, by you.

Comment: My issue is I can't find a reliable way to define the "neighbor". I'd like find which shapes share any part of their border with the selected region. I'm selecting regions by targeting the entire path when clicked on, so there's no real issue with strokes being on top of each other. There's never any overlap between shapes (being a map, no region that would share space with any other). Apologies for not being clear! I'll update my original post to show my original attempts at doing this if that's helpful, though I have since realised the methods I was trying to use simply wouldn't work.

Comment: Well yes, usually maps data define the *fill* area, so if you had some stroke on these paths, they'll overlap (by half the stroke-width. For instance take [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvs5atmh/) and hover over #Region01). I thought that was why you wanted to have a "neighbor" class, to overcome this issue. Now I understand it's not your intention.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Yes, you're quite correct that adding a stroke introduces an overlap. An overlap isn't an issue for me, but seeing as there is one I could perhaps use it as the test for whether a shape has any neighbors. I.E., if there's an overlapping shape, that shape is a neighbor. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (to my knowledge), no built-in ways to do it no...

Now, you can setup an algorithm yourself to do the check, but it might come a bit computationaly intensive.

As a first step, you'll only check for the Bounding-Boxes of your paths, eliminating all the ones that are not going to hit your path in any way:

```
function intersectBoxes(bb1, bb2, padding = 0) {
  // half padding (we'll add it in every direction of our rects)
  const pad = padding / 2;
  // helper function to get clean labels
  const getCorners = (bb) => ({
    left: bb.x - pad,
    top: bb.y - pad,
    right: bb.x + bb.width + pad,
    bottom: bb.x + bb.width + pad,  
  });
  const r1 = getCorners(bb1);
  const r2 = getCorners(bb2);
  // check intersection
  return r1.left <= r2.right &&
    r1.right >= r2.left &&
    r1.top <= r2.bottom &&
    r1.bottom >= r2.top;
}
// usage 
intersectBoxes(path1.getBBox(), path2.getBBox(), 2);
// @return Boolean
```

Once this is done, you can start an heavier check. SVG2 introduces a new [isPointInStroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInStroke) method, but that's currently supported only in a few browsers. So you may need to polyfill it. I didn't found one, so I quickly made a monkey patch instead using the 2DContext equivalent.

With the help of this method, we then only have to grab the x, y coordinates of one of our paths all along its stroke and to call this method repeatedly.

```
function slowHitCheck(p1, p2) {
  // we will walk along the smallest of both paths
  const smallest = p1.getTotalLength() < p2.getTotalLength() ? p1 : p2;
  const longest = smallest === p1 ? p2 : p1;
  const length = smallest.getTotalLength();

  let pos = 0;
  while(pos < length) {
    const pt = smallest.getPointAtLength(pos);
    if(longest.isPointInStroke(pt)) return true;
    pos += stroke_width;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```js
$(".map").click(function(event) {
  var $mapTarget = $(event.target);

  if ($mapTarget.is("path")) {

    $(".region").attr("class", "region");
    const neighbors = getNeighbors($mapTarget[0], $('#Map')[0]);
    neighbors.forEach(node => {
      node.classList.add('neighbour');
    })

    $mapTarget.addClass("active");
  } else {
    return;
  }
})

function getNeighbors(target, root, stroke_width = 1) {
  const targetBB = target.getBBox();
  return [...root.querySelectorAll('path')]
    .filter(path =>
      path !== target && // not the target
      // fast check BBoxes
      intersectBoxes(path.getBBox(), targetBB, stroke_width / 2) &&
      // walk the path
      slowHitCheck(path, target, stroke_width)
    );

}

function intersectBoxes(bb1, bb2, padding) {
  const pad = padding / 2;
  const getCorners = (bb) => ({
    left: bb.x - pad,
    top: bb.y - pad,
    right: bb.x + bb.width + pad,
    bottom: bb.x + bb.width + pad,
  });
  const r1 = getCorners(bb1);
  const r2 = getCorners(bb2);
  return r1.left <= r2.right &&
    r1.right >= r2.left &&
    r1.top <= r2.bottom &&
    r1.bottom >= r2.top;
}

function slowHitCheck(p1, p2, stroke_width) {
  const smallest = p1.getTotalLength() < p2.getTotalLength() ? p1 : p2;
  const longest = smallest === p1 ? p2 : p1;
  const length = smallest.getTotalLength();

  let pos = 0;
  while (pos < length) {
    const pt = smallest.getPointAtLength(pos);
    if (longest.isPointInStroke(pt)) return true;
    pos += stroke_width;
  }
  return false;
}



/* Half related code below: 
 * Monkey Patches SVGGeometryElement's isPointInStroke
 *  and is isPointInFill.
 * You can check the revision history
 *  for a simpler version that only worked for SVGPathElements
 */
// Beware untested code below
// There may very well be a lot of cases where it will not work at all
if (window.SVGGeometryElement && !window.SVGGeometryElement.prototype.isPointInStroke) {
  monkeyPatchSVGIsPointIn();
}
function monkeyPatchSVGIsPointIn() {
  const ctx = get2DContext(0, 0);
  const default_ctx = get2DContext(0, 0);
  Object.defineProperty(SVGGeometryElement.prototype, 'isPointInStroke', {
    value: function isPointInStroke(point) {
      returnIfAbrupt(point);
      const path = generatePath2DFromSVGElement(this);
      setUpContextToSVGElement(ctx, this);
      ctx.stroke(path);
      return ctx.isPointInStroke(path, point.x, point.y);
    }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(SVGGeometryElement.prototype, 'isPointInFill', {
    value: function isPointInFill(point) {
      returnIfAbrupt(point);
      const path = generatePath2DFromSVGElement(this);
      setUpContextToSVGElement(ctx, this);
      ctx.fill(path, this.getAttribute('fill-rule') || "nonzero")
      return ctx.isPointInPath(path, point.x, point.y, this.getAttribute('fill-rule') || 'nonzero');
    }
  });

  function returnIfAbrupt(svgPoint) {
    if (svgPoint instanceof SVGPoint === false) {
      throw new TypeError("Failed to execute 'isPointInStroke' on 'SVGGeometryElement':" +
        "parameter 1 is not of type 'SVGPoint'.")
    }
  }

  function generatePath2DFromSVGElement(el) {
    const def = el instanceof SVGPathElement ?
      el.getAttribute('d') :
      (el instanceof SVGPolygonElement ||
        el instanceof SVGPolylineElement) ?
      ("M" + el.getAttribute('points').split(' ').filter(Boolean).join('L')) :
      "";
    const path = new Path2D(def);
    if (!def) {
      if (el instanceof SVGLineElement) {
        path.lineTo(el.getAttribute('x1'), el.getAttribute('y1'))
        path.lineTo(el.getAttribute('x2'), el.getAttribute('y2'))
      }
      if (el instanceof SVGRectElement) {
        path.rect(el.getAttribute('x'), el.getAttribute('y'), el.getAttribute('width'), el.getAttribute('height'));
      } else if (el instanceof SVGCircleElement) {
        path.arc(el.getAttribute('cx'), el.getAttribute('cy'), el.getAttribute('r'), Math.PI * 2, 0);
      } else if (el instanceof SVGEllipseElement) {
        path.ellipse(el.getAttribute('cx'), el.getAttribute('cy'), el.getAttribute('rx'), el.getAttribute('ry'), 0, Math.PI * 2, 0);
      }
    }
    return path;
  }

  function setUpContextToSVGElement(ctx, svgEl) {
    const default_ctx = get2DContext();
    const dict = {
      "stroke-width": "lineWidth",
      "stroke-linecap": "lineCap",
      "stroke-linejoin": "lineJoin",
      "stroke-miterlimit": "miterLimit",
      "stroke-dashoffset": "lineDashOffset"
    };

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)) {
      ctx[value] = svgEl.getAttribute(key) || default_ctx[value];
    }
    ctx.setLineDash((svgEl.getAttribute("stroke-dasharray") || "").split(' '));
  }

  function get2DContext(width = 0, height = 0) {
    return Object.assign(
      document.createElement("canvas"),
      { width, height }
     ).getContext('2d');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.region {
  fill: green;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
}

.region:hover {
  fill: lightgreen;
}

.active {
  fill: red;
}

.neighbour {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="Map" class="map" viewBox="0 0 125 75">
  <g>
    <path id="Region01" class="region" d="M0,0 L 0,50 L 50,50Z"/>
    <path id="Region02" class="region" d="M25,25 L 75,25 L 75,75Z"/>
    <path id="Region03" class="region" d="M0,50 L 25,50 L 25,75 L 0,75Z"/>
    <path id="Region04" class="region" d="M100,0 L 125,0 L 125,25 L 100,25Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Just wanted to add, that if you work with matrices on the same level as `getBBox()` gets called, you would have to add those to the BBox before passing to `intersectBoxes`.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you so much for this excellent example! Especially, the concept of pre-analyzing intersecting or adjacent Bounding-Boxes (before heavy path geometry related calculations) is truly elegant. Besides, the aforementioned fast BBoxCheck is already surprisingly accurate, albeit not perfect.